# I got an error when use array loader in webpack 2.2, why?

Tags: arrays, webpack, loader

I have the config like this:

```
module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.(js|es|es6|jsx)$/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: {
            loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }
    }]
}
```

But the style-loader and css-loader can't run. It seems that the loaders can not be array. Moreover, I can't open the page of webpack 2 documents. Would you please tell me how to solve this problem?

This is the error:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration.module.rules[1].use should be one of these:
>      non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, query? } | function | [non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, query? }]

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by changing it to

> {
>       test: /.sass$/,
>       use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
>   }